# Find $a$, when $\tan a$ is given in terms of $\tan1^{\circ}$ and $\tan2^{\circ}$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\alpha = {(1+\tan1°)(1+\tan2°)-2 \over (1-\tan1°)(1-\tan2°) - 2}$ and $\alpha \in (0°, 90°)$ then $\alpha$ is equal to?

This is task from my faculty entrance exam workbook. This is mostly high school level and I can only assume that I need to use addition trigonometry formulas or double angle, but I do not how, may someone give me some steps or hint how to do this?

EDIT: I haven't done Componendo and Dividendo ever, is there any other way to solve this equation?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will keep that in mind for future questions and edit this one!

Comment: try expand first

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\tan x\tan y-1+(\tan x+\tan y)}{\tan x\tan y-1-(\tan x+\tan y)}$$

Applying Componendo and dividendo ,

$$\dfrac{\tan\alpha-1}{\tan\alpha+1}=\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan x\tan y-1}$$

Now $$\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan x\tan y-1}=-\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}=-\tan(x+y)$$

and $$\dfrac{\tan\alpha-1}{\tan\alpha+1}=\tan\left[\alpha-45^\circ\right]$$

Finally, $\tan(-A)=-\tan A$

Comment: No, $\tan\left[\alpha+45^{\circ}\right]=\frac{\tan\alpha+1}{1-\tan\alpha}$.

Comment: @user26486, Thanks for your observation

Comment: Componendo and dividendo was applied in the form $$\frac{(\tan\alpha+1)+(\tan\alpha-1)}{(\tan\alpha+1)-(\tan\alpha-1)} =\frac{(\tan x\tan y-1)+(\tan x+\tan y)}{(\tan x\tan y-1)-(\tan x+\tan y)}$$

Comment: @user26486, Could you reach the destination ?

Comment: Componendo and dividendo says $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\iff \frac{b+a}{b-a}=\frac{d+c}{d-c}$$  

Let $a=\tan\alpha-1, b=\tan\alpha+1,c=\tan x+\tan y,d=\tan x\tan y -1$.

Comment: @user26486, Why don't you simplify to use $\tan(A\pm B)$

Comment: You said you used componendo and dividendo (c&d), but you didn't show how you used it. If you insist on using c&d, then your statement  $$\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\tan x\tan y-1+(\tan x+\tan y)}{\tan x\tan y-1-(\tan x+\tan y)}\implies \dfrac{\tan\alpha-1}{\tan\alpha+1}=\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan x\tan y-1}$$

can be proved by 

$$\frac{(\tan\alpha+1)+(\tan\alpha-1)}{(\tan\alpha+1)-(\tan\alpha-1)} =\frac{(\tan x\tan y-1)+(\tan x+\tan y)}{(\tan x\tan y-1)-(\tan x+\tan y)}\implies \dfrac{\tan\alpha-1}{\tan\alpha+1}=\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{\tan x\tan y-1}$$

Comment: @user26486, As $\tan45^\circ=1,$ $$\dfrac{\tan\alpha-\tan45^\circ}{1+\tan\alpha\tan45^\circ}=\tan\left(\alpha-45^\circ\right)$$  right?   Finally if $\tan x=\tan A,$  what can we conclude?

Comment: You said you used c&d, but you didn't give an explanation. You probably didn't use c&d because you don't even understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $$\tan\alpha=\frac{(1+\tan 1^o)(1+\tan 2^o)-2}{(1-\tan 1^o)(1-\tan 2^o)-2}$$ $$=\frac{\left(1+\frac{\sin 1^o}{\cos 1^o}\right)\left(1+\frac{\sin 2^o}{\cos 2^o}\right)-2}{\left(1-\frac{\sin 1^o}{\cos 1^o}\right)\left(1-\frac{\sin 2^o}{\cos 2^o}\right)-2}$$ $$=\frac{(\sin 1^o+\cos 1^o)(\sin 2^o+\cos 2^o)-2\cos 1^o\cos 2^o}{(\sin 1^o-\cos 1^o)(\sin 2^o-\cos 2^o)-2\cos 1^o\cos 2^o}$$
$$=\frac{\sin 2^o\sin 1^o+\sin 2^o\cos 1^o+\cos 2^o\sin 1^o+\cos 2^o \cos 1^o-2\cos 2^o\cos 1^o}{\sin 2^o\sin 1^o-\sin 2^o\cos 1^o-\cos 2^o\sin 1^o+\cos 2^o \cos 1^o-2\cos 2^o\cos 1^o}$$
$$=\frac{(\sin 2^o\cos 1^o+\cos 2^o\sin 1^o)-(\cos 2^o\cos 1^o-\sin 2^o\sin 1^o)}{-(\sin 2^o\cos 1^o+\cos 2^o\sin 1^o)-(\cos 2^o\cos 1^o-\sin 2^o\sin 1^o)}$$ $$=\frac{\sin (2^o+1^o)-\cos (2^o+1^o)}{-\sin (2^o+1^o)-\cos (2^o+1^o)}$$ $$=\frac{\cos 3^o-\sin 3^o}{\cos 3^o+\sin 3^o}$$ $$=\frac{1-\tan 3^o}{1+\tan 3^o}$$ $$=\frac{\tan 45^o-\tan 3^o}{1+\tan 45^o\tan 3^o}=\tan(45^o-3^o)=\tan 42^o$$ $$\implies \tan \alpha=\tan 42^o $$$$\implies \color{blue}{\alpha=42^o} \quad (\forall \space 0<\alpha<90^o)$$